# ESS: ess-request-a-process defaults to "S"

Tags: r, emacs, customization, ess

Quite often I find myself with bunch of R processes running in ESS buffers. There's a convenient Lisp function `ess-request-a-process` that asks for R process, and brings it to front. The only downside is that it somehow defaults to **S**, so each time I'm about to make a switch, I have to type **R**, ad nauseam.

I tried customising the `ess-language` variable, but even if I set value to "R", i.e. 4 for current session, or even if I save settings for future session, as soon as I type `C-c C-k`, automagically **S** appears once again. It's very annoying, and I really don't want to end up with `C-x C-b` and then `C-s` for desired R session! =)

I even tried setting `(setq-default ess-language "R")` in `.emacs`, but with no luck...

BTW, I'm running Emacs v. 23.1.1 on Linux Mint and Emacs v. 23.2 on Arch Linux, with ESS v. 5.12. If that's relevant, I run Emacs from terminal with `-nw` argument. Here's my `.emacs`:

```
;; start server
(server-start)

;; load ESS
(require 'ess-site)
(require 'ess-rutils)

;; set HTML help as default
(setq inferior-ess-r-help-command "help(\"%s\", help_type = \"html\")\n")

(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ess-help-kill-bogus-buffers t)
 '(ess-rutils-keys nil)
 '(show-paren-mode t))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
```

So... how to set **R** once and for all? (I don't use S/S+/SAS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not know about this function so far. <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> is bound to `ess-force-buffer-current` in ESS buffers.

[edit: <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>  is indeed bound to ess-request-a-process in iESS, in ESS it's `ess-force-buffer-current`]

In any case the variable you have to customize is `ess-dialect`

```
(setq-default ess-dialect "R")
```

It's buffer-local variable and some other stuff in `ess-mode-hook` might set it a different value.

Check it in each buffer with  <kbd>C-h v</kbd>  `ess-dialect`

Additionally, if you already running several processes then `ess-switch-process` (<kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>)  might be the right way to go.
[edit: it will not jump to a process but just reset the associated process of the current ESS buffer]

[edit: After dwelling deeper on the issue it turned out that `ess-request-a-process` uses `ess-language` variable were the `ess-dialect` seems to be more appropriate. The problem is that each time an ess-inferior process starts it resets the global value of `ess-language`. This is why setting it in your case didn't work.

Here is a quick fix:

```
(defun ess-set-language ()
  (setq-default ess-language "R")
  (setq ess-language "R")
  )

(add-hook 'ess-post-run-hook 'ess-set-language t)
```

]

Comment: I can't seem to find `ess-dialect` variable. `C-c C-v` is reserved for R function help, while `C-c C-s` is reserved for `ess-execute-search`. I feel like I'm doing something terribly wrong here...

Comment: @aL3xa, sorry, variable help is of course `C-h v ess-dialect`, corrected now.`C-c C-s` is bound to ess-execute-search in iESS buffer not ESS buffers. What's the point to switch the process in the process buffer? :)

Comment: Well... I'd like to do the pointless switch! =) Now, is it possible to just set R instead of S?

Comment: @aL3xa, I see now, there is some confusion in terminology. Switching of process, means changing the subprocess association for current buffer. This is what ess-switch-process does. And you can not change the associated subprocess of the buffer in which the process runs (inferior ESS). What you probably mean, is switching to another process buffer (i.e. jumping). But that completely different functionality, C-c C-z for instance.

Comment: Setting ess-dialect should work. All internal functions use it as a default name to crank or switch to processes. Doesn't work for you?

Comment: Ok, I got deeper into it. It's a bug in ess.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Lisp, so... if you say that it's a bug, then bug it is! =) Anyway, your quick fix works, and when I do `C-c C-k` there's shiny new R instead of S! Thanks with sugar on top! =)

Comment: Actually, it's not working properly... I cannot acces `ess-smart-underscore` from default keybinding. =/ It's a bug, I'll post it to ESS mailing list.

Comment: @aL3xa, the fix should not affect anything in your configuration. Works perfectly right for me. I was planing to send the patch directly to developers along some other small fixes.

Comment: Wait a sec, if you apply your fix, you can access `A-_`? Cause I can't! O_o

Comment: @aL3xa Yes, that's exactly so, the smart underscore function works for me, but I have a very personalized configuration. See in the mail I posted today on the ESS help list for a direct fix. Just modify ess-language into ess-dialect in the ess-request-a-process function.

Comment: OK, this definitely doesn't work for me. Smart underscore is not working, but `C-c C-k` certainly does. I guess one can't win them all... =) Thanks anyway!